# Java.util list to csv file download

Tags: java, google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore

I have a `java.util.List` of entities queried from the GAE Datastore that I want to parse to a .csv file and give users capability to click a button to download this file. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Generate a link to a servlet. When the servlet is invoked, execute your query, get the list of entities, transform them to CSV (there are plenty of free libraries to do that), then write the result to the response output stream with the appropriate content type set. Without knowing where in this process you have a problem, I won't detail more.

Comment: What's a good library for this? I tried OpenCSV but the Java FileWriter class isn't supported by App Engine.

Comment: And why would you use FileWriter? What does that have to do with OpenCSV?

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#can-I-write

Comment: But you don't want to write it to a file. You want to write it to the response output writer: `new CSVWriter(response.getWriter())`.